# pip fails to install/search with winsock error 10053: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine on windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I am having hard time finding out why I cannot get a connection from (administrator) command line to pypi.org.

Environment: Windows 10

Python version: 3.7.3 64bit

Install location: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\

Firewall was off

cmd was running as an admin

Error message:

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection
aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))': /simple/pylint/

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.pscs.co.uk/how_to:10053

> 10053 errors are actually quite rare usually, but there are a couple
>   of cases we know of which can cause them:
>   ▪  if the 10053 error is
>   being reported by your email client or by VPOP3 when downloading
>   and/or sending email, it could be a problem with your antivirus
>   software. Both McAfee VirusScan 8 and Norton Antivirus 2004 have been
>   found to give these errors sometimes, but other virus scanners or
>   versions may also cause these errors. See below for more information.
>
> ▪  if the 10053 error is reported in the VPOP3 Status Monitor program,
>   then this usually means that the VPOP3 server has stopped for some
>   reason. It may be that it was stopped by someone else, or it may have
>   failed with an application error.
>   ▪  some early releases of version 2
>   of vPOP3 use the recycle bin quite extensively. Windows is sometimes
>   unable to deal with these requests and this can result in 10053
>   errors. To eliminate this as a possible cause of 10053 errors, ensure
>   you are running at least version 2.5.0b of vPOP3.

Comment: did you find your answer?